# Finding all combinations of elements in an array using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I know there have been many questions similar to this one, and I've reviewed them for the past hour, however I couldn't figure out how to solve my problem using the answers provided.

My task is as follows:

> Write a program that prompts the user for a list of cities, where
>   each city has a name and x and y coordinates. After all cities
>   have been entered, the program should use a recursive algorithm
>   to print the length of all possible routes that start at the
>   first city entered, end at the last city entered, and visit every city
>   in the list. For each route, the program should print the name
>   of each city visited, followed by length of the route.

I broke down the problem and I can figure out out most of the code. What got me stuck was finding all possible combinations between the 1st and last cities. How the hell do I manage that?
I'm trying to solve it with a simple array of 5 integers and for the life of me I can't figure out how to print all combinations.

Could you kindly assist me in overcoming this hideous problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a short version of your code ([mcve] ).  Best is to include coded test data to avoid user input.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an Array I would suggest you use a graph.

You can read more about the Travelling Salesman Problem here [TSP](http://www.example.com/) or [Brute-force for TSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703827/brute-force-algorithm-for-the-traveling-salesman-problem-in-java)

Comment: I am not familiar with graphs but I will have a look, thanks friend!

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to use recursive algorithm?

If no, here is my suggestion:

Suppose entered cities are A, C1, ..., Cn, B which A and B are first and last cities. First and last cities could not be changed, so you should compute all combination of n city. To compute all combinations, you can count from 0 to 2^n-1. For each value of counter you have a path form A to B. Each bit of each counter value could be related to one city (Ci). Now for each value of counter you can print a path form A to B (with some Ci):

- If related bit of a city in counter value is 0 so related city is not a viewed city in the path
- If related bit of a city in counter value is 1 so related city is a viewed city in the path.

Comment: Thank you Hadi, unfortunately I am forced to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It is a well-known graph approach. If you have knowledge about graphs, just taking a glance at [DFS (recursively)](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Graph/Undirected/Depth-first_search) most likely meets your expectation.

Comment: I am not familiar with graphs but I will have a look, thanks friend!